# How to display random rows without repetition in laravel?

Tags: php, sql, laravel

```
//controller method to get random rows    
public function random() {
    $book= Book::inRandomOrder()->first();
    return $book;
}
```

for example in my db I have 8 rows. I want to display random row every-time without repetition. means after completing all rows it will allow to show again.here my results are like this 1,3,2,5,8,7,3,6,5,4  but what I want is 1,3,2,5,8,7,6,4,...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Recommend improving code formatting.

Comment: does the first(); method returns only one row ? then how you get multiple rows here ?

Comment: Just I want to display one row. for that I'm using `first()` method.

Answer (score 0):

This will return only random books

```
public function random() {
    $book= Book::inRandomOrder()->distinct()->get();
    return $book;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `group by`:

```
public function random() {
            $book= Book::inRandomOrder()->
                      ->groupBy('any column you want')
                      ->get();
            return $book;
        }
```